# Save URL to disk in Chrome (under XFCE 4.8)

Tags: google-chrome, xfce, url

How can I save a URL in Google Chrome running under XFCE 4.8? There is no "save URL" option under the wrench menu and dragging the favicon simply doesn't work.

edit: I don't want to bookmark the URL, I want to save it on the disk (like in Windows: [image]).

Comment: you want to bookmark the page ?

Comment: no, i want to save it on the disk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click on Customize & control chromium (wrench) > Tools > Create Application Shortcuts

[image]

[image]

Comment: wow, that was in a peculiar place. usually these use to be under file (or wrench) menu. would you by chance know how to do the same under `iceweasel`/`firefox`?